# IBM Worklight - Can we create a custom dialog for Direct Update?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How can we use custom dialog box for direct update in worklight 6.0?
Is there any option in wlclient.js? I don't know where it should be customized in the application.

Comment: if your question is answered - please mark this answer as "Answered".

Answer (score 0):

Worklight 6.0 does not provide developers the ability to create a "custom dialog box" for Direct Update.

You can submit a feature request: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html

Answer (score 0):

So Idan already answered, but I did a lot of digging prior to his answer and I thought I'd share my findings just because I spent so much time on it.

Sifting through the code, through all the checks it does to see if a Direct Update is needed, it calls an update method for the app. It utilizes a Cordova plugin called 'WebResourcesDownloader'. In turn it calls the necessary native components and that's how you get a native handler for the downloader (it is in the worklight-android.jar for Android). So, long story short, you can't customize the box itself because its rendered via the plugin/native components and you can't modify the plugin directly (not that I know of at least).

However, you can at least update all the notification messages surrounding the update in the messages.js within the wlclient folders. =)